prove AP-SUM is NP-complete
EDIT: I had a translation error. Instead of "unuary", it's binary.
AP-SUM is the language defined in the following way:
A word in the language AP-SUM is a pair <S, t>,
so that S is a finite set of integers written in unary, S = {n1, n2, ..., nk}, and t is a natural number written in unary.
AP-SUM = {<S, t> | S = {n1, ..., nk}, and for some {m1, ..., mi} ⊆ S we have t - 10 ≤ Σmi ≤ t + 10}
I need to show it is an NP-complete language. The part proving it's in NP was fine, and I'm stuck on the reduction part.
It's known that it needs to be from SUBSET-SUM, but I'm not sure how to create the output, specifically the "t" part.

In subset sum the numbers are given in binary. When the numbers are given in unary then subset sum becomes in P. So if you are reducing from subset sum, then there is no clear way of converting binary to unary in polynomial time.

Where did you encounter this task/exercise?  Please credit the original source.

I cannot credit it due to copyright - it's a question from a former exam at my university. I will ask the professor to clarify what you mentioned and edit accordingly.

@BaderAbuRadi I'm tagging you to let you know I clarified the issue with my professor and edited the question accordingly.

Well, subset-sum is NP-complete, assuming the input numbers are encoded in binary. Now the idea of the reduction simply follows by distributivity of the sum. Therefore, the intuition is to try and multiply the input numbers, including the target, by the same factor. Specifically, a reduction from subset-sum operates as follows. Given input $(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k, t)$, the reduction outputs $(11\cdot n_1, 11\cdot n_2, \ldots, 11\cdot n_k, 11\cdot t)$. The reduction is clearly polynomial.
Regarding correctness, for the first direction, if there is a set $S\subseteq [k]$ with $\sum\limits_{i\in S} n_i = t$, then $$11\cdot \sum\limits_{i\in S} n_i =  \sum\limits_{i\in S} 11\cdot n_i = 11\cdot t$$
In particular, $$ 11t - 10\leq \sum\limits_{i\in S} 11\cdot n_i \leq 11t + 10$$
and so the set $S$ also witnesses that $(11\cdot n_1, 11\cdot n_2, \ldots, 11\cdot n_k, 11\cdot t)$ is in AP-SUM.
For the other direction, if there is a set $S\subseteq [k]$ with $$ 11t - 10\leq\sum\limits_{i\in S} 11n_i \leq 11t+10$$ then $$ 11t-11 <\sum\limits_{i\in S} 11n_i <11t+11$$ and so $$t-1 <\sum\limits_{i\in S} n_i <t+1 $$ hence the sum $\sum\limits_{i\in S} n_i $ equals $t$. Therefore, the set $S$ also witnesses that $(n_1,  n_2, \ldots,  n_k,  t)$ is in subset-sum.

It's unlikely to be NP-complete.  There is a polynomial-time algorithm, using the standard dynamic programming algorithm for subset-sum.   This algorithm runs in polynomial time when all integers are provided in unary.
